# How to get value from the formdata in angular js

Tags: php, jquery, angularjs

Here is my form

```
<form>
<input class="text_box1" type="text" name="email" ng-model="forget.email" >
<button style="width:auto" class="sign_up" ng-click="doForget(forget)">Get a Password</button>
</form>
```

Inside my `app.js` I have

```
.when('/forget', {
                title: 'forget',
                templateUrl: 'resources/views/forget.php',
                controller: 'authCtrl'
            })
```

And inside the `authCtrl` controller

```
$scope.doForget = function (customer) {
        Data.post('eloquent.php', {
            customer: customer
        }).then(function (results) {
            if (results == "1") 
            {
                $location.path('login');
            }
        });
    };
```

I am calling eloquent.php

But how can i get the value of email from the `forget.php` and send to `eloquent.php` ?

Comment: You can get the value by `email = $scope.forget.email;` to get the value and you can make it in in local storage and send it to your `eloquent.php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the value of the `forgot.email` by

`forgotemail = $scope.forgot.email;`

And then store it in local storage and retrieve there

`localStorage.setItem("forgotemail ", "forgotemail ");`

And then do the call by

```
$http.post('eloquent.php', {forgotmail: forgotmail}).then(function (results)
{
//your other code here
}
```